# failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream,

Tags: magento, nginx, magento2

I'm getting a weird error in my Magento Installation after I try to checkout an order.

```
[error] 20850#0: *221038 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) 
while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, 
server: xxx.nl, request: "POST /rest/default/V1/guest-
carts/1b7f447450f3a9a062acdaaf62959048/payment-information
```

I only see this error whenever I click on the pay now button on the checkout page.

Nothing excepts the error in the logs.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

check and set proper log level in nginx.conf

```
error_log log_file [ log_level ]
```

possible options: emerg | alert | crit | error | warn | notice | info | debug